# post image in json to server ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

i converted the image to data and data to string. but server is not showing any image. can you please tell me the problem,
here is my code...

```
imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(chosenImage);
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
            [dict setValue:_textView.text forKey:@"Title"];
            [dict setValue:_textView.text forKey:@"Body"];
            [dict setValue:@"170" forKey:@"M_ID"];
NSString *str = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];

                [dict setValue:str forKey:@"Media"];

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"...url....."]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody: jsonData];
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;


    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse:&response error: &error];
```

Comment: Is this your url? :P `@"...url....."`

Comment: Please check in your backend if the image is successfully inserted into database or not.

Comment: no i put my company's data base url there in my code.. i just mentioned like that

Comment: db is taking all the details except image.. in image column it is showing nothing in db

Comment: Please check with backend developer what type of datatype he is expecting to receive for image -ByteArray,Base64  etc. I had converted the image to base64 String, backend developer converted back the base64 string

Comment: Exactly, there is the issue, check how your backend dev  is accepting image. If you send base64 then in backend it should be decoded. From your end everything is fine, just check backend.

Comment: my backend developer said that server is expecting the bolb image format.. can anyone tell me how to convert the image to blob

Answer (score 0):

Why you are converting whole dictionary to NSData, you have to convert only Image to NSData. First convert image into NSData and then add it to dictionary.

Comment: i tried that too... by adding NSData to Dictionary and then converted to json. but im getting error if i do like that..     'Invalid type in JSON write (NSConcreteMutableData)'

Comment: Ok first convert image to NSData and then convert it into basr64 string like NSString *imgStr=[imgData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
                    and then add it into your dictionary  like [dict setObject:imgStr forKey:@"file"];

Answer (score 0):

i would prefer you to convert image to Base64 and then upload it to server.This is the best method to upload image to server.

```
ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetslibrary assetForURL:imageURL
           resultBlock:resultblock
          failureBlock:nil];


UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
imgProfile.image = chosenImage;

CGFloat compression = 0.9f;
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, compression);
strEncoded=[data mp_base64EncodedString];
```

Then upload this strEncoded to server and ask you server side developer to convert this base 64 .